# Vertical <hr> pushes <h2> downward

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 2 vertical lines in between two heading tags, but it keeps pushing the headings down... Is there anyway I can fix this?

I've tried using "align-content: fex-start" and "padding-top: 10px".

[image: visual example of problem]

HTML and CSS

```
   <hr class="vertical-hr">
   <h2 class="inline-h">200+<br />Pack<br />Downloads</h2>
   <hr class="vertical-hr">
   <h2 class="inline-h">7<br />Content<br />Packs</h2>
```

(CSS)

```
   .inline-h {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   padding: 5px;
   }
   .vertical-hr {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 125px;
   }
```

Comment: vertical-align:top

Answer (score 0):

The flex align directives don't work for any other display then flex.
You should use display flex on a parent div. That would make things a lot easier.
Flexbox can do what you want with ease. I use inline style here to shorten the code.

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <hr class="vertical-hr">
  <h2 class="inline-h">200+<br />Pack<br />Downloads</h2>
  <hr class="vertical-hr">
  <h2 class="inline-h">7<br />Content<br />Packs</h2>
</div>
```

It would be even better to drop the hr completely.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
   margin-right: -0.75rem;
   margin-left: -0.75rem;
}

.flex > * {
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  border-right: thin groove;
}

.flex > *:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class='flex'>
      <h2>200+<br />Pack<br />Downloads</h2>
      <h2>7<br />Content<br />Packs</h2>
      <h2>4<br />More<br />Stuff</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. How would I align it all to the middle?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inline-h {
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}

.vertical-hr {
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<hr class="vertical-hr">
<h2 class="inline-h">200+<br />Pack<br />Downloads</h2>
<hr class="vertical-hr">
<h2 class="inline-h">7<br />Content<br />Packs</h2>
```